# Autostart a python program in RaspberryPi

Tags: python, raspbian

I am making a project related to RaspberryPi and Xbee, where it is essential that python program should start when i give power to RaspberryPi.

I saw a techniqe on a udemy lecture, where it was said-
sudo crontab -e
A file will open. Go at the end of the file and then type
@reboot sudo python3 /home/pi/mycode.py
Reboot the Raspberrypi.
Even by doing this, i am not getting any success. 
Please suggest where i am going wrong. This is a easy problem but i am stuck here. Please help.

Comment: Cron jobs might help you with this. Have a look at this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

Comment: Thank you Shantanu.  I was missing & at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
```

Go to the last line of the script and add:

```
echo Running at boot 
sudo python /home/pi/sample.py
```

There are various other ways in this blog
https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/

Comment: Giving import error:  No module named gps.   The program is running well when i am running it using putty. Strange kind of problem. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: You might have to make module global with `sudo pip install gps`. I also found a guide on using crontab [https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/)